# How do I simplify the replacing codes below

Tags: r

To replace the ClientType column with other Strings like:

```
#Change the label of ClientType
data$ClientType[data$ClientType=="a"]<-"Android"
data$ClientType[data$ClientType=="b"]<-"ios"
data$ClientType[data$ClientType=="c"]<-"web"
data$ClientType[data$ClientType=="d"]<-"type4"
data$ClientType[data$ClientType=="e"]<-"Type5"
...
```

Thank you for any comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `dplyr` `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(ClientType = case_when(ClientType == "a" ~ "Android", 
                                ClientType == "b" ~ "ios",
                                ClientType == "c" ~ "web",
                                ClientType == "d" ~ "type4",
                                ClientType == "e" ~ "Type5",
                                TRUE ~ NA))
```

---

Another option is to use `recode`

```
recode(data$ClientType,a = "Android",b = "ios",c = "web", d = "type4", e = "type5")
```